# DisplayTag Export is Exporting all bean fields

Tags: jsp, displaytag

I'm using displaytag's Excel export with the [ExcelHssfView](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/displaytag-export-poi/apidocs/org/displaytag/export/excel/ExcelHssfView.html) to export a table as Excel.  However, every field in the tables backing bean is being written out to the exported table, instead of just the defined columns.  My displaytag configuration is:

```
export.types=excel
export.csv=false
export.pdf=false
export.excel=true
export.xml=false

export.excel.class=org.displaytag.export.excel.ExcelHssfView
export.excel.decorator=org.displaytag.sample.decorators.HssfTotalWrapper
export.ExcelView=org.displaytag.export.ExcelView
```

And in the jsp

```
    <display:setProperty name="export.excel" value="true" />
    <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="invoiceList.xls" />
    <display:setProperty name="export.amount" value="list" />
    <display:setProperty name="export.excel.include_header" value="true" />
    <display:setProperty name="export.excel.label" value="Download Invoices" />
</display:table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**All** the `<display:column>` tags had their `media` attribute set to `html`, which prevented them from being referenced by the Excel export (expecting the `all` or `excel` media), so displaytag defaulted to passing in all the bean columns.

```
<display:column media="html" headerClass="sortable"
            title="Invoice Amount" class="textDisplayArea" >
         $ <c:out value="${invoice.invoiceAmount}" /> 
</display:column>
```

changed to

```
<display:column headerClass="sortable"
            title="Invoice Amount" class="textDisplayArea" >
         $ <c:out value="${invoice.invoiceAmount}" /> 
</display:column>
```

And it worked.